# Android Exoplayer caching m3u8 audio for offline support

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am creating a music application.
I have used Exoplayer V2.8.0, So far I have achieved to play, pause next, prev, shuffle, repeat all songs using controls in-app and also with notification.

But all of this works only in online mode.

Now I want to add offline support to this app and allow a user to download the song offline and play while they are offline.

Audio files we are getting are *.m3u8 files.

But my problem is user should not access those downloaded files outside of my app. I have tried using one approach but it gives the mp3 files downloaded and combined from the different segments of the m3u8 file.

Can anyone guide me or give me sample or tutorial on how can I download the segments only and at the time of playing I can use that segment and play audio offline?

Comment: `m3u8` is obviously not an audio file. in best case, it may contain a stream location.

Answer (score 0):

There is one suggestion for you,

If you want to create an offline player with .m3u8 or any other file then after download saves your file into your package folder with some of the different formats. Then while using that convert that specific formatted to mp3 or other which will help out for offline music play.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local http proxy server ([NanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd)). Start the server and point your ExoPlayer to `127.0.0.1` so you can monitor the requests. Cache the m3u8 playlist plus the downloaded files for the first time you see a request. Next time when your proxy detects the same request, just play the files from cache.

Comment: thanks man, but can you please give me more details explanation on how to do this.

I will sure check the library you have provided.

Comment: You can find examples if you search for "Android MediaPlayer proxy". This one looks useful: https://github.com/danikula/AndroidVideoCache